# Swift 3 - Add Text to UIView Pop up

Tags: ios, swift, text, swift3, popup

I want to display a pop up with some fixed text in it.

I found this for the pop up.

```
    // Define a view
    var popup:UIView!
    func showAlert() {
    // customise your view
    popup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
    popup.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor

    // show on screen
    self.view.addSubview(popup)

    // set the timer
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.dismissAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

  func dismissAlert(){
    if popup != nil { // Dismiss the view from here
      popup.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
```

I can't seem to add a label in the showAlert() and display it.

I tried calling a seperate function in showAlert that gets the label text, that works but it wont dismiss.

How can I add a text/string/Label to the pop up in the showAlert function itself? I want to use UIView itself, not AlertController.

Comment: Where is your attempt to add a label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
popup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))

let lb = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
lb.text="anything"
popup.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor

// show on screen
self.view.addSubview(popup)
popup.addSubview(lb)
lb.center = popup.center
```

Comment: I was just about to delete the question. I arrived at the same answer and got it to work. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @KanavBatra If it works then you should accept Sh_Khan's answer.